# How to find and update one nested structure in a vector in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a requirement to find if a structure exists with a vector which contains a nested structure:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

typedef struct Obj {
    int id[128];
    int len;
} ID;

typedef struct Details {
    ID id;
    int fwid;
    int respfmt;
} IDDetails;

std::vector<IDDetails> details =
{
   { { { 2, 2, 1 }, 3 }, 0, 1 },
   { { { 2, 2, 2 }, 3 }, 0, 2 }
};

class A {
public:
    int SetDetails(std::vector<IDDetails>& ids, ID &id)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    ID d = { { 2, 2, 1 }, 3 };
    a.SetDetails(details, d);
    return 0;
}
```

The only logic I have  in **SetDetails** is to traverse through vector and then verify its details but is there a better way to exactly match and update that structure in the vector?

Comment: I think if you use vector to store then you must travel all element to find special element. Instead of using vector, you can use balance tree(map in STL) or hashtable to store `IDDetails` to find faster an element( O(nlogn) and O(1) for each query)

Comment: @TaQuangTu It's possible to perform a binary search on a vector, if the data is sorted.

Comment: @Steve of course yes. but it take O(logn) time for each insert operation and O(logn) time for search operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

// ...

bool operator==(ID const &lhs, ID const &rhs)
{
    return lhs.len == rhs.len && std::memcmp(lhs.id, rhs.id, lhs.len) == 0;
}

// ...

auto f = std::find_if(ids.begin(), ids.end(), [&](IDDetails const &i) { return i.id == id; });
```

?

Comment: I think std::find_if also travel through the vector until the iterator meet the to be found item.

Comment: This is the answer I think, although @Swordfish offers no explanation. Use some kind of search function (here, a simple iteration until the item is found, but a binary search or other kind of search could be made to reduce the time). The predicate function (here a lambda) can perform arbitrarily complex logic to determine the match. In other words 1) Pick a search algorithm 2) Write a predicate function 3) Find your thing 4) Update it.

Comment: @Steve Swordfish is not quite sure what the OP thinks of, when he asks for "a better way". So I merely provided an example and hope for feedback from the OP.

Comment: Thanks the sample code - it does provides a way out but as in conversation in the thread please let me know of other kind of search - its always a great passion to learn new things